# Contributors in GitHub Repo

Tags: git, github

I cloned the code from a repository to get some inspiration for my own work.

Now after I have made many changes, I would like to push in another repository of my own.

I tried to do this but I see two contributors, me and the owner of the cloned repo.
Can someone help me to get a repository with only one contributor (me), since the new repository intent will have little to do with the initial repository?

Comment: What is embarrassing? I don't get it.

Comment: There is nothing to help with. There _are_ two contributors. This is the "open" in "open source". That's what GitHub is all about. Don't worry be happy. Or make the repo private. However I still think a fork, not a clone and push, is a much better way to go.

Comment: @matt There is something to help with, once you understand the OP's intent. See my answer, which should clarify said intent, and answer the question.

Comment: @matt a fork in GitHub word is often made with the intent of contributing back to the upstream (forked) repository, which is not the case here. A simple reference in the modified `README` should be enough here, once the repository has been recreated.

Comment: @VonC I don't agree. I often fork, and people _very_ often fork from me, with no intention of contributing to upstream.

Comment: @matt Absolutely: I understand that, technically, you can fork and never contribute back. I agree. But here, the intent is to get inspiration of an existing code base, and transform it radically to make something unrelated with the initial project. In that context, seeing "contributors" would make little sense, as they would not have contributed to the current *new* state of the code base.

Comment: If your goal is a new independent repository hosted in your GitHub account, the correct method is **fork** and not **clone**. The reason you see other contributors is the remote repository is the **origin**. If you haven't made changes yet, log in to GitHub, fork the original repository and then clone your repository to your desktop/system. If you have made changes review @VonC answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to:

- clone again the original repository, in a new local folder
- delete the `.git/` subfolder
- initializing and adding (under your `user.name`) the initial codebase

  ```
  git init .
  git add .
  git commit -m "Initial import from codebase https://github.com/x/y"
  ```
- replaying the commits you have done locally during your extensive modification of the first cloned repository (the one where you see external contributor to what is, essentially, a new project from an old codebase)

  ```
  git remote add firstRepo ../firstClonedFolder
  git fetch firstRepo
  git switch main
  git rebase --onto main firstRepo/main~10 firstRepo/main
  ```

Replace 10 by the number of commits you have done.

Delete your GitHub repository and recreate it empty: you can push to it your new local repository, which will have only your own commits.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/me/myNewEmptyRepo
git push -u origin main
```

Don't forget to add in the `README.md` a clear reference to the original repository from which you get your inspiration, as well as a link to their author.

Comment: While this solution might work, not crediting the work of someone else is at the very least dishonest and we should not encourage such behavior.

Comment: @Exitare I agree. I have completed my answer to include proper attribution of the original code base.

Comment: Thank you for taking care of this issue!

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i'm trying to do it but i'm not founding  the .git subfolder. I'm searching it in the folder of the cloned repo...is  it right? did you mean, erase all the contents in the new cloned repo?

Comment: @FrancescoMollica The .git subfolder is usually hidden. What OS and git version are you using? Deleting that folder would erase the past history of the code base, not the code base itself.

Comment: ah, ok! I'm working on a remote virtual machine. I just use terminal and VS

Comment: @FrancescoMollica OK. It is best to switch to command line on this remote VM.

Comment: yes, with "ls -a" i found it..now i delete it

Comment: @FrancescoMollica Reminder: delete the .git of the *new* local cloned repository, not of the local repository were you started making commits and modification. The goal is to create a new repository in which you will import your commits.

Comment: i clone the repo, first i deleted .git subfolder then i make only one big commit with all my changes. Now i make git remote...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240515/discussion-between-vonc-and-francesco-mollica).